# HTML website navigation menu is flipped backward

Tags: android, html, css, iphone, browser

I recently changed my FLASH header and menu to be a simple HTML with some CSS menu. After finishing the menu, everything looks fine on IE, Chrome, and FireFox, but on Phones and Safari the menu is flipped horizontally.

it has changed from A B C to C B A

I thought it is something that is not compatible with Safari, but I tried downloading chrome on my iPhone and I still have that issue.

here is the link to my website. 
http://khaneyeparastesh.com/indexHome.htm

Comment: I see the same in FF, Chrome and Safari, but as a hint, is it possible your issue comes from not having rtl direction anywhere?

Comment: I've added **float:left;** to the **#menu li** and that fixed the direction on all the devices. The only issue now is that on Mobile phones it is not centered.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes that happens when you set the float attribute to something like:

```
nav li a {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: I've never had that in my style. I just added **float:left;** to the **#menu li** and changed the padding, it is looking good. The only issue now is that it is centered on the computer, but on the phone it is shifted to the left a little bit.